# Ambiguous tags - file

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Should we create separate tags if a tag is ambiguous? I'm thinking of the `file` tag for starters... I think I've seen it mean file the data structure, and `file` the command. Are these even different enough? Should there be a separate tag? (I was thinking `file-command` ) thoughts?

*update*
There is one other option... we could delete all instances that refer to the "data structure" I just don't see that as being important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't have amibiguous tags; that just seems wrong. I'm for `file-command` as an extra tag.

But that's going to be more work for you guys (moderators)?

*comments on update:*

I don't see how that is an alternative? There is still going to be questions that will need to be retagged `file` or `file-command`.

I think we should just create the `file-command` tag, retag the obvious questions and let social nature take its course...

---

[image]

Comment: I don't think much more work

Comment: On the contrary, it's going to be more work for *you* guys; the ability to retag comes at 200 reputation :). But xeno is right, they really do need to be kept separate

Answer (score 2):

We should, and `[file-command]` is probably good since people who type `[file]` should see it in the suggestion box and choose it, which limits the amount of work retaggers have to do

Comment: `[file-command]` was not shown as a suggestion when I typed `[file]`. I had to search on meta to find the right tag, which I did finally did after sumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

I will also endorse file-command, but i think we should add files for the data structure and depreciate and remove file.