# What to do when finding a case of ambiguity between two tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Although it seems similar, it is a different case from [this one](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126/ambiguous-tags-file).

My question goes on the other hand; and is that reviewing several questions about [rxvt-unicode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rxvt-unicode), I have found that there are times that the label indicated is `urxvt` and other times `rxvt`:

[image: tags image]

I keep in mind that `urxvt` is a fork of [`rxvt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rxvt), so there may be the difference. However, in all the cases I am seeing they refer to `urxvt` (as it is more logical that it is used today by most).

I don't know if there are cases similar to this with other ambiguous labels. But this makes dealing with the categories that reference these software a bit messy.

Wouldn't it be interesting to unify the two, perhaps in `rxvt` as a generalization? What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be interesting to unify the two, perhaps in rxvt as a generalization?

Indeed, and that's exactly the case now. Note how the suggestion says [rxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rxvt) with the subtext "also: urxvt"? That's because [urxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urxvt) is already [a *synonym*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rxvt/synonyms) of [rxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rxvt) (since 2015). You can't actually add the [urxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urxvt) tag to a question now - if you do, the system will automatically convert it to [rxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rxvt) when you save the post.

It's also listed separately with 33 posts because posts which were tagged with [urxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urxvt) before the tag synonymization was completed aren't automatically converted to use the [rxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rxvt) tag, and so still belong to the synonym.